# Move owncloud data from one account to an other

Tags: owncloud

Since renaming an owncloud accounts seems impossible according to [#1333](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/1333) I want to create a new account and move all data from the old account to the new. Then delete the old account

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

With ownCloud 9.0 this can be done with:

```
occ files:transfer-ownership user1 user2
```

see: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_files/file_sharing_configuration.html#transferring-files-to-another-user